# CAS REST authentication API accepts text/* but not application/* content type

Tags: rest, security, cas

I have configured my `CAS` server to activate `REST` authentication, as per [these instructions](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/restful+api). However, in order for it to work, I must submit my credentials in plain text (content type `text/html` or `xml`) and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as per the instructions. The credentials are lost when sent in the latter format.

I am uncomfortable sending my login credentials in plain text. Is this a bug in CAS and how can it be fixed? I am assuming it is less secure to send login credentials as text content type vs application, as the latter (I assume) does hash (or somehow else obfuscates) the content sent.

I should also mention that I had to make a fix to a bug in CAS due to which credentials were being lost regardless of the content type, by implementing [this solution](https://blog.imaginea.com/sso-using-cas-restful-apis-and-java/) in my `maven overlay`. After that, only text-based content types worked and CAS does authenticate (albeit I find it annoying that the service returns HTML and not XML/JSON or even plain text, for the ease of programmatic processing).

**RELATED:**  [REST API endpoint /v1/tickets appears to lose credential request parameters](https://github.com/apereo/cas/issues/886)

Answer (score 1):

Content-type has no effect on the confidentiality of data in the request. Sending it with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in a request is not more (nor less) secure than `text/html` or `text/xml` if only confidentiality is considered. There is no additional security value in using any of those in a request, somebody having access to the raw request source (a MitM attacker) will see request contents either way. HTTPS effectively mitigates this risk with regard to MitM attackers on the network inbetween nodes, but not on endpoints where SSL is terminated (the source and target computers, and also any node inbetween that terminates SSL, like for example a company proxy with a trusted root certificate on clients - a fairly common setup).

As for the possible security *benefit* of using `text/plain` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558596/sending-login-credentials-as-text-html-content-type/40600245#40600245) to your other question. In short, using `text/plain` may prevent some CSRF attacks.